# How can I get the selected VALUE out of a QCombobox?

Tags: qt, qcombobox

In Qt, I can get the **`selected text`** of a `QComboBox` by using the 
`combobox->currentText()` method.
How can I get the **`selected value`**?

I searched for help but I couldn't find a method `currentData()` which I expected to find. I could only find `combobox->currentIndex()`

Is there a smarter way to do it other than `combobox->itemData(combobox->currentIndex())`?

Update: This is no longer necessary as of Qt 5. A `currentData()` method has been added http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentData-prop

Answer (score 104, accepted):

It seems you need to do `combobox->itemData(combobox->currentIndex())` if you want to get the current data of the QComboBox.

If you are using your own class derived from QComboBox, you can add a `currentData()` function.

Comment: @Patrice Bernassola  However the switch operation of type 'QVariant' :`combobox->itemData(combobox->currentIndex())` is illegal !!! Why ?

Comment: This doesn't work if nothing is selected i.e. `currentIndex = -1`.
It will either return the data from the last index or raise an error if the QComboBox is empty.

Answer (score 29):

This one can get the text of current index:

```
QString cb = cbChoice ->currentText();
```

Comment: How does this help? `currentText` is what the OP is aware of already...

Answer (score 24):

you can set QVariant data for all items, then you can get the value when you need it.

there is an example code for this situation:

```
ui.comboBoxSheetSize->addItem("128 m", QVariant(128));
ui.comboBoxSheetSize->addItem("256 m", QVariant(256));
ui.comboBoxSheetSize->addItem("512 m", QVariant(512));
ui.comboBoxSheetSize->addItem("1024 m", QVariant(1024));

...

void Page::onComboSheetSizeChanged( int index )
{
 int value = ui.comboBoxSheetSize->itemData(index).toInt();
}
```

---

by the way, i think i misunderstood your question. i think the way you get data is smart enough?

Answer (score 11):

The member function QComboBox::currentData has been added since this question was asked, see this [commit](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/tavestbos-qtbase/commit/cada1fb4ef04b64593156be1190884c314d7c041)

Comment: For documentation see: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentData-prop. The property is available since Qt 5.2.

Answer (score 8):

I had same issue

I have solved by

```
value = self.comboBox.currentText()
print value
```

Comment: That's the label text, not the value.

Answer (score 3):

This is my OK code in QT 4.7:

```
 //add combobox list 
    QString val;
   ui->startPage->clear();
    val = "http://www.work4blue.com";
    ui->startPage->addItem(tr("Navigation page"),QVariant::fromValue(val));
    val = "https://www.google.com";
    ui->startPage->addItem("www.google.com",QVariant::fromValue(val));
    val = "www.twitter.com";
    ui->startPage->addItem("www.twitter.com",QVariant::fromValue(val));
    val = "https://www.youtube.com";
    ui->startPage->addItem("www.youtube.com",QVariant::fromValue(val));

   // get current value
    qDebug() << "current value"<< 
       ui->startPage->itemData(ui->startPage->currentIndex()).toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm astonished that there isn't an activated signal and have the same problem. I solved it by making a subclass of QComboBox. I think it's better to avoid having to directly access the object and call its functions because that means more tight coupling and goes against Qt's philosophy. So here's the class I made that works for me.

```
class SmartComboBox : public QComboBox {

    Q_OBJECT

private slots:

    void triggerVariantActivated(int index);

public:

    SmartComboBox(QWidget *parent);

signals:

    void activated(const QVariant &);

};
```

And the implementation

```
void SmartComboBox::triggerVariantActivated(int index)
{
    activated(itemData(index));
}

SmartComboBox::SmartComboBox(QWidget *parent)
:QComboBox(parent)
{
    connect(this, SIGNAL(activated(int)), this, SLOT(triggerVariantActivated(int)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is old, but maybe, somebody need an actual answer.

In the QGIS 3.4 you can get the value from the `QComboBox` with the method `currentData()`.

Example: `comboBox.currentData()`

Link: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentData-prop

Answer (score 0):

I did this

```
QDir path("/home/user/");
QStringList _dirs = path.entryList(QDir::Dirs);
std::cout << "_dirs_count = " << _dirs.count() << std::endl;
ui->cmbbox->addItem(Files);
ui->cmbbox->show();
```

You will see with this that the QStringList named _dirs is structured like an array whose members you can access via an index up to the value returned by _dirs.count()

Answer (score -1):

I had the issue and

```
QString str = m_UI->myComboBox->currentText();
```

solved this.

Comment: Again, as others wrote above, this is *selected text*, NOT *selected VALUE*. A different thing.

Answer (score -1):

if you are developing QGIS plugins then simply

```
self.dlg.cbo_load_net.currentIndex()
```

Comment: Nope, this is as well not *selected `VALUE`*. Selected *`TEXT`*, selected *`VALUE`* and selected *`INDEX`* are completely different things. Only in a coincidence may `index` be equal to `value`. If people want to use combo, they need to learn and understand the difference. And to my best understanding, in Qt the VALUE is a bit extended when using data models.

Answer (score -2):

I know I'm very late but for those who still have that problem, it can be solved easily.
I use Qt 5.3 and it works fine. No need to create a function or all that.

```
int valueComboBox;
valueComboBox = comboBox->currentIndex();
```

and it works ! 
Hope it helps !

Comment: index is not the same as value

Answer (score -5):

I confirm the easiest way is to do this:

```
uiAnalyseAssets::AnalyseAssets(QWidget *parent)
: QWidget(parent)
{
ui.comboBox->addItem("text1");
ui.comboBox->addItem("text2");

...
}

void mainFunction::yourFunction( int index )
{
 int value = ui.comboBox->currentText();
}
```

Comment: Wait a second -- doesn't `QComboBox::currentText()` return a `QString`? How do you arrive at a sensible `int`? And what do you want to do with your parameter `int index`?