# QComboBox returns None Type . How to get Current Data?

Tags: python, indexing, pyqt, qcombobox

I've implemented 2 QComboBoxes with one having items manually inserted every time and another one having items inserted with a list (I'm using Python )

But when i attempt to get the current value of Combobox , it returns **None** .
I proceeded as specified in this question :
[I referred this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056915/how-can-i-get-the-selected-value-out-of-a-qcombobox)
i have provided wat i've coded ."command" and "option" are QComboBoxes ( Pardon me for bad style)  Is there any mistake in Indexes ?

```
    self.command.insertItem(1,'Convert')
    self.command.insertItem(2,'Compose')
    self.command.insertItem(3,'Animate')


    self.option.insertItems(268,list)
```

and  retrieval :
       `self.selected_com=self.command.itemData(self.command.currentIndex())
        self.selected_opt=self.option.itemData(self.option.currentIndex())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't selected a current item in the combo boxes. If there is no current item and insert a new item with `insertItem`, it's not selected automatically as the current one. You probably want to call `self.command.setCurrentIndex(1)` and `self.option.setCurrentIndex(1)`.

From the documentation about `currentIndex()`:

> By default, for an empty combo box or
>   a combo box in which no current item
>   is set, this property has a value of
>   -1.

From the documentation about `itemData()`:

> Returns the data for the given role in
>   the given index in the combobox, or
>   QVariant::Invalid if there is no data
>   for this role.

From the documentation of PyQt:

> Any Python object may be used whenever
>   a QVariant is expected. None will be
>   interpreted as an invalid QVariant.

Comment: thank u Rosh , i think u've done some reasearch for me. But when i run as u said , it displays "QComboBox has no attribute named setCurrentItem()" . Is there any other way to get ComboBox's data ?

Comment: I misspelled setCurrentIndex.

Comment: No u're correct . But i also tried setCurrentIndex . Whatever i set the index , it returns None !!!

Comment: You also haven't set any data for the Qt.UserRole role (i.e. there's no third argument in your insertItem calls), so the data is None.

Comment: Thank u . I've modified that as u said: `self.selected_com=self.command.itemData(self.command.currentIndex(),2)`  and it worked . I still don't know wat is user role . ha :)

Comment: Perhaps you want to use `PyQt4.QtCore.Qt.EditRole` or `PyQt4.QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole` instead of a hard-coded `2`. `2` is probably the former.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for fetching current data from comboBox:

```
QString qualification=ui->comboBox->currentText();
QDebug()<<qualification;
```