# Retrieve different text from combo box in Qt Designer (pyqt)

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt-designer

this could sound strange and it is more a curiosity then a question.

I have a simple combobox with 2 elements in Qt Designer.

The 2 combobox elements are `vertical` and `horizontal` but for the script I'm writing I need to get only `v` or `h`.

Usually I easily do it with a loop like:

```
name = self.combbox.currentText()

if name == 'vertical':
    name = 'v'
else:
    name = 'h'
```

and that's ok.

I was just thinking if there is a way in Qt Designer to assign a kind of `tag` to the elements so the user sees the complete text but with the code it can be retrieved the `tag`.

Thanks to all

Comment: `QIdentityProxyModel`

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can do this with Qt Designer alone (see [How can I add item data to QComboBox from Qt Designer/.ui file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35142276/how-can-i-add-item-data-to-qcombobox-from-qt-designer-ui-file)).

With some extra Python, though, you can add use `setItemData()` to add whatever extra data you want ([How can I get the selected VALUE out of a QCombobox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056915/how-can-i-get-the-selected-value-out-of-a-qcombobox)) and retrieve it with `itemData()` and `currentIndex()`.

Comment: thanks for the answer.. Well in my case it is easier to loop and re-assign the values.. Anyway, thanks!